# How to use string interpolation in a resource file?

Tags: c#, variables, string-formatting, interpolation, resource-files

I would like to use a resource file to send an email. In my resource file I used a variable "EmailConfirmation" with the value "Hello {userName} ... "

In my class I used:

```
public static string message (string userName)
{
   return Resource.WebResource.EmailConfirmation
}
```

The problem is that the return says "Hello {userName}" instead of "Hello Toto".

Comment: String interpolation only works with string literals.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can't make use of string interpolation in the context of resources. However you could achieve that you want by making use of `string.Format`. Write to your resource file something like this:

```
Hello {0}
```

and then use it like below:

```
public static string message (string userName)
{
   return string.Format(Resource.WebResource.EmailConfirmation, userName);
}
```

**Update**

You can add as many parameters as you want. For instance:

```
Hello {0}, Confirm your email: {1}
```

And then you can use it as:

```
string.Format(Resource.WebResource.EmailConfirmation
    , userName
    , HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(link))
```

Comment: yes, I thought of it, but it actually is more complex because in my variable "EmailConfirmation" I used this : "Hello {userName}, Confirm your email : {HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(link)}"
And "HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode" is not taken in cocideration

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use placeholders like that instead of digits (I understand...) then you can do this:

```
return Resource.WebResource.EmailConfirmation.Replace("{userName}",userName)
```

You can keep daisychaining .Replace commands for additional placeholders that you use.

```
return Resource.WebResource.EmailConfirmation.Replace("{userName}",userName).Replace("{loginDate}",loginDate).Replace("{notes}",notes)
```